# In TFS 2018, how do I set demands for a Deployment group?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a server setup using TFS 2018 that currently builds our software and triggers a release to deploy the binaries to my target system. I want to be able to only deploy the binaries to specific machines within a Deployment group based on the Capabilities each target has defined. I can see the capabilities for each target within my deployment group but no way to reference them.
I don't see an option to set Demands for the Deployment Group Phase in my Release Definition, only for a Build Agent.

How can I set Demands for my Deployment group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deployment groups don't have demands, but they *do* have tags. You can tag the machines in your deployment groups however you want, then specify that a Deployment Group phase should only run on a certain set of tags.

Comment: I was using the tags but I was hoping for finer control as each system might have a different hardware configuration that could be exposed as a capability that is important to know. Oh well. I'll work around it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Since deployment groups don't have demands, but tags, you could try to use an agent phase on your release instead of a deployment group.

Release/build agents are the same, they share the same code base.
When you use an agent phase on a release pipeline, you can still use deployment tasks like to deploy IIS apps, they just will use WinRM, where you will be capable of remote deployments.

For instance, your deployment agent could be installed on server 1 and your target IIS in another server. With deployment groups, you only can deploy where the agent is installed.